# unable to get delete changes in destination db using debezium as source and confluent jdbc sink connector

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

My  Dockerfile which i used to download sink connector and mysql jdbc driver

```
FROM debezium/connect
ENV KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR=$KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR/kafka-connect-jdbc
ENV MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION 5.1.39
ARG KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION=5.5.0
RUN curl -k -SL "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    | tar -xzf - -C /kafka/libs --strip-components=1 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}-bin.jar
RUN mkdir $KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR && cd $KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR &&\
    curl -sO https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-jdbc/$KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION/kafka-connect-jdbc-$KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION.jar
```

i kept this file with no extension named as Dockerfile in my present working directory and used the below command to bulid that docker image

```
docker build . --tag kafka-connect-sink
```

```
docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper
```

```
docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka
```

```
docker run -it --rm --name mysql -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw debezium/example-mysql


docker run -it --rm --name mysqlterm --link mysql --rm mysql:5.7 sh -c 'exec mysql -h192.168.99.102 -P3307 -uroot -pdebezium'



docker run -it --rm --name mysqldest -p 3308:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw debezium/example-mysql


docker run -it --rm --name mysqltermdest --link mysqldest --rm mysql:5.7 sh -c 'exec mysql -h192.168.99.102 -P3308 -uroot -pdebezium'
```

```
docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka --link mysql:mysql --link mysqldest:mysqldest kafka-connect-sink
```

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "inventory-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "root", "database.password": "debezium", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.whitelist": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.test" } }'
```

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "inventory-connector-sink", "config": { "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysqldest:3306/inventory?useSSL=false","connection.user": "root", "connection.password": "debezium", "topics": "dbserver1.inventory.customers", "table.name.format": "inventory.customers" ,"auto.create": "true" ,"auto.evolve":"true","delete.enabled":"true", "insert.mode": "upsert", "pk.fields": "id", "pk.mode": "record_key" ,"transforms": "unwrap", "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope" } }'
```

Note: to delete an unwanted config file we can use below

```
curl -X DELETE 192.168.99.102:8083/connectors/inventory-connector-sink
```

```
docker run -it --rm --name watcher --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka watch-topic -a -k dbserver1.inventory.customers
```

Everything is working fine only problem if i delete any row in source db it is not refelcting in destination db eventhough i am using delete.enable as true and pk.mode as record_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please either set https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/configuration/event-flattening.html#extract-new-record-state-drop-tombstones to `true` or https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/configuration/event-flattening.html#extract-new-record-state-delete-handling-mode to `none`.

Either of those two options will ensure that the sink connector will receive the tombstone event which is the indicator for delete. When not present then delete records are filtered out.